# | Save content of message in different variables

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

How do I save the content of a message, separate it, and save it on different variables?
**message.content**

> EX: "Hello" is in var[0], "everyone!" is in var[1].

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
var words = message.content.split(' ');
```